# Detail about communication packets error log

Tags: mysql, errors, log, error-log

On MySQL error log `/var/log/mysql/error.log` I'm getting this error couple of times during the day:

> 2021-08-23T07:30:17.660730Z 455148 [Note] Got an error reading
> communication packets

My question is how can I know which packets are these? How can I solve this or gain more information about the problem?

Comment: i doubt that there is a simple solution ti that problem, but you can look here https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/16/mysql-got-an-error-reading-communication-packet-errors/ for a more detailed anaylysis

Comment: In your my.cnf or my.ini  in [mysqld] section, use of log_warnings=2 will provide additional details related to the cause.  This is a dynamic varaible and from MySQL Command Promt, SET GLOBAL log_warnings=2; will record additional information in your error log without a stop/start of the instance.